# A/C works but doesn't blow out front dash vents

Tags: ford, ac

2004 Ford Freestar

The A/C works all over the van, even the dash on top and sides, at least that's where I feel it. The vents that are on the front of the dash, the ones you can adjust to hit you, they "sometimes" work. I bought the van last week. They told me the A/C did not work, but it did, for a few days. Then today I turned it all on then went back in my home to grab some stuff, got in it was cool but the vents weren't working. I drove with the a/c on & it got cold. It works just not blowing well. Can anyone please help? Thank You

Comment: Your vehicle has a very complicated AC-Heat system, you should take it to a professional that can pull codes and properly diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the main problem is a vacuum leak. When you loose vacuum the ac/heater will default to the defrost position.  Check for vacuum leaks first.

Comment: Get a copy of the appropriate sections of the shop manual. It should have a schematic that describes the flap positions at the different control positions. I also suspect it's a vacuum issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one or more of the Blend Door Actuators are broken, so that when you tell the climate control where to send air, it can't actually do it. If you have Auto Climate Control, you have two of these (I think it's 4 if you have manual A/C and Heating). They're about $30 each, if you can replace them yourself.

However... It would be unusual for both actuators to break at the same time. Before spending money, check fuses 12 and 8 under the dashboard; they may have blown.

Comment: Whoever you are; If you're going to downvote my answer, at least have the common courtesy to explain why.

Comment: PeteCon- you gave a good answer and thanks for the fuse locations

Answer (score 0):

A late reply, but was the issue solved?

Have you checked the AC filter? It tends to get choked over time, especially given that it pulls all the air from the front/engine compartment. You will see a lot of cooling but no air. Or it could be the 2 vents are blocked due to some debris clogging the passage to these 2 vents.

It is usually located behind the glove compartment/under the dash. Take it out and give it a good dusting. Should clear out nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the unplug vacuum cord by the passenger side...then look for the thing that looks like a plunger by your front window... and plug them to things back up....it should blow then...if not you'll need more 134a or your AC compressor is not spinning....
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Mine ended up being that the vacuum line broke off inside the rubber plunger. Poked it out with an awl and re-attached at everything is working now. Looks like it might have been manipulated or banged around during a battery install. Thanks!